# Oops concept - getting unexpected result

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, copy-constructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
   /* Class data members */
public:
   Test(const Test &t) { /* Copy data members from t*/ cout<<"copy\n";}
   Test()        { /* Initialize data members */ cout<<"create ";}
};

Test fun()
{
    Test t;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    Test t1;
    Test t2 = fun();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is ->  **create create**.

Why is the constructor only called twice ?

According to me the output should be -> **create create create**  .

Comment: [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Comment: In addition to the above comment you might also want to look at the [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: @BiagioFesta  thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your `main()`:

`t1` is not explicitly initialized so it uses default constructor (Printing one **create**)

`t2` is explicitly initialized by the return value from `fun()`, the `Test t2` part of the statement is only declaration of the variable.

Inside `fun()` the local variable `t` is not explicitly initialized so the default constructor is called (Printing second **create**)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect **create create create**, but rather **create create copy copy** (without copy elision).

- The 1st create is `t1` in `main()`.
- The 2nd create is `t` in `fun()`.
- The first copy is `t` being copied to the return of `fun()`.
- The second copy is the return value of `fun()` being copied to `t2` in `main`.

You can see this with [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/Fgso1a) with and without the option -fno-elide-constructors.